# How to handle onsubmit with Domina

Tags: clojurescript

I've been trying to write an equivalent for the following in cljs using the [Domina library](https://github.com/levand/domina):

HTML:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$("#my-form").submit(function() {
    console.log("submit suppressed");
    return false;
});
```

A solution not to my satisfaction (without Domina library which is very verbose):

```
(set! (.-onsubmit (.getElementById js/document "my-form")) #(do
                                                              (.log js/console "submit suppressed")
                                                              false))
```

I've tried many solutions which all failed - all somewhat similar to:

```
(listen! (by-id "my-form") :submit #(do
                                      (log "submit suppressed")
                                      false))
```

It is on purpose that I don't use the click event, because I also want the function to be executed when the form is submitted by code or keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return `false` from within a `jQuery` event handler, the library will automatically call `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` (for more info see [here](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)). Calling this functions is the right way to control the behaviour of the `event`.

Domina wraps `js/Event` in something that `ClojureScript` understands. So you can call `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` directly, without using the Javascript interop. You can read more about this neat trick here: https://github.com/levand/domina#event-objects.

This trick is probably what is causing returning `false` to not work at all. The way this trick is implemented (take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/levand/domina/blob/master/src/cljs/domina/events.cljs#L30)) is by wrapping your function with another function that always return `true`.

So your code should be more like this:

```
(listen! (by-id "my-form") :submit
         (fn [e]
           (do
             (log "submit suppressed")
             (prevent-default e)
             (stop-propagation e))))
```

Comment: I've put alerts in between the calls to the event. As soon as the first event call is made - no matter if it is preventDefault or stopPropagation everything after is ignored (no more alerts are seen and the form is submitted). Perhaps the Domina wrapping is messing with things

Comment: Maybe you are right, I will take a look and try to find a way to resolve it.

Comment: The problem was Domina wrapping of the `Event`. I updated my answer, sorry about posting the wrong answer (I wasn't able to test the code before posting).

Comment: For some reason the moderators rejected your edit. I edited the answer myself.